# Create distance matrix keeping sign R

Tags: r

To create a distance matrix of Euclidian distances:

```
x <- c(5,1,3,5,3,2)
dist(x, diag=T, upper=T)

  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 4 2 0 2 3
2 4 0 2 4 2 1
3 2 2 0 2 0 1
4 0 4 2 0 2 3
5 2 2 0 2 0 1
6 3 1 1 3 1 0
```

Am I missing a super easy quick function for maintaining the sign for distances. e.g. the following output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  4  2  0  2  3
2 -4  0 -2 -4 -2 -1
3 -2  2  0 -2  0  1
4  0  4  2  0  2  3
5 -2  2  0 -2  0  1
6 -3  1 -1 -3 -1  0
```

Comment: `outer(x,x,\`-\`)` ?

Comment: thanks - I completely whiffed on remembering that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want `outer`:

```
outer(x,x,`-`)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    4    2    0    2    3
#[2,]   -4    0   -2   -4   -2   -1
#[3,]   -2    2    0   -2    0    1
#[4,]    0    4    2    0    2    3
#[5,]   -2    2    0   -2    0    1
#[6,]   -3    1   -1   -3   -1    0
```

Comment: Or `-sapply(x, '-', x)`